# Microsoft Emotions API Get Recognition in Video Operation Result

Tags: c#, api, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

How do I return the status and results from a video I posted to the emotions api using Get Recognition in Video Operation Result?

I can successfully run the Get Recognition in Video Operation Result using an operation id of a video I uploaded, but the response does not show the status of the video and the results from the emotions API but only shows the following:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
Headers:{ 
Pragma: no-cache 
apim-request-id: 010962c0-f907-4ba3-a7fd-564ddff7f97d 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 02:33:16 GMT 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
Content-Length: 16048 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 }
```

I've tried using the same oid in the  open api testing console

(https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f8d4471984551ec0a0984f/console)

and the response returns the status and the results from the emotions api.

I'm using the following code from the API reference:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

        var uri = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/operations/{oid}?" + queryString;

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've pasted, it looks like you *do* have a response, 16048 bytes of JSON.

Since you're using C#, I think you'll save a lot of effort by using the [client library](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Windows), authored by members of the Cognitive Services team.  If you use Visual Studio, you can simply pull down the NuGet package.

If you don't want to use the prebuilt library, you'll need to parse out the JSON yourself.  The JSON will be in `response.Content`.

Comment: I was able to access the response content using:

string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

I was originally using the client library for C#, but I found that it was too slow for me to actually use. 

Thanks for your help!